# Two URL links and opening the second URL in the first opened URL page

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have two  tags in my page having URLs of different sites. Both tags have target="_blank" so that they will open their URL in different window.
Now if a user clicks on first  tag, then it will open a window of first URL. IF user instead of closing that window, clicks on the second  tag then i want the first opened window to refresh itself and open the URL of second  tag. Is that possible?

Comment: Just chose your own window name instead of `_blank` - then it will be re-used.

Comment: Possible with javascript if allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag has a `target` property which takes in the possible values

- `_blank`: To open linked document in new window
- `_self`: To open linked document in same frame (default)
- `_parent`: To open linked document in parent frameset
- `_top`: To open the linked document in full body of window
- `<name_of_frame>`: You can provide a name to the frame to open the linked document. (In the example below we choose the name `popupwindow` as a sample name given. You could give a different name too.)

Referencing the next anchor click to the same frame will reload the contents in the same frame that was open. Here's a simple example of what you're looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://google.com" target="popupwindow">Open Google</a>
    <a href="https://bing.com" target="popupwindow">Open Bing</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your anchors like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="/first" target="first" onclick="refresh()">First link</a> 
<a href="/second" target="second">Second Link</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function refresh(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if( "first" in window ){
         first.location.href = e.target.href;   
    }
    else {
         window.target = window.open( e.target.href, 'second' );   
    }
};
```

Comment: This should be possible with HTML5 by setting the same `target` framename. Using js to do the same seems like an overkill.